# Command (e.g. `g++`) does not point to the same binary when run from the terminal or from (neo)vim

Tags: neovim, command-line, binary-file

I have `NVIM v0.4.3` on macOS Mojave version 10.14.6
I have different version of `g++` compilers on my machine and made the following alias in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias g++="/usr/local/bin/g++-9"
alias g++Old="/usr/bin/g++"
```

I want to compile and run the following script on my Mac that I named `count6.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(11);
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(8); // vec{4, 1 8}
    for(auto elem: vec)
        cout << elem << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the command the

```
g++ count6.cpp -o count6; ./count6
```

I get the following output:

```
11 1 8 %
```

However if I type the same command from within nvim, I get the following warnings:

```
:!g++ count6.cpp -o count6; ./count6
count6.cpp:12:9: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-ex
tensions]
    for(auto elem: vec)
        ^
count6.cpp:12:18: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-ex
tensions]
    for(auto elem: vec)
                 ^
2 warnings generated.
11 1 8
```

Ny interpretation is that the command from within nvim does not point to the same binary. How can I make point to the same binary?

Comment: It may be that aliases dont have effect when using `:!` (which wouldnt surprise me). Try `:!type g++`. Also make sure it isn’t a PATH issue. Lastly, use a makefile or other buildsystem that you can invoke with `:make`—then the problem disappears.

Comment: many thanks for the comment @D.BenKnoble. `:!type g++` gives indeed `g++ is /usr/bin/g++`. Do you have other hint for implementing your 2 other advices?

Comment: Be explicit and use `g++-9`. If you were using the native quickfix feature through `:make` (which appeared in the late 90's) instead of the old Vi (!= vim) `:!compilername` trick, you should be able to just set `:let $CXX = 'g++-9'` -- I expect your flavour of `make` is correctly configured with all the usual implicit rules.